# How to use 'url-loader' with angular-cli compiler

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v7

Usually I run my projects and build my SASS files with WebPack, which I have the rules in way that generates a CSS files with `url-loader` converting all `url(...)` inside that sass file to a dataURI.

so `background: url('my-file.svg')` would be converted to `background url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,SoMeGiBbeRiShHeRe')`

I'd like to know if there is a way to achieve this with the `ng` compiler? I researched a bit on this, and the way to do it was to use `ng eject` but that option is no longer available.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this function, but is this a standard Sass feature? It strikes me as odd that you would need to configure Angular to tweak anything.

Comment: It's not sass in particular, it's this WebPack pluging https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-loader - I'd like to use it with angular-cli because I need this functionality to convert my svg icons into base64 `data:image`

Comment: OK, it sounds to me that you need to customize the webpack process. Have you seen [this article](https://codeburst.io/customizing-angular-cli-6-build-an-alternative-to-ng-eject-a48304cd3b21)

Comment: apparently the feature I want is returning an error. It has been reported already but no fixes yet :( https://medium.com/@stepan.techs/while-adding-new-loader-in-scss-669d8edd40b7